# Question about building a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm interested in building a Chrome extension that would allow users to import Google docs to Medium.com. I'm a bit green, and was wondering what you all would suggest as far as programming languages go. I have the most experience in Python, but am open to learn another if it would provide a better experience for the end user.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Questions on "what programming language I should use" are vastly opinion based and does not belong on Stackoverflow. Also note that if you are writing a chrome extension the only tool you have at your disposal is javascript unless the extension communicates with a server, which will not be exposed to the end user. You can write the extension in any language you want but it will have to compiled to Javascript at which point you will lose all the advantages of the language, which again will not effect the end user.

Comment: An extension would make sense if it'll activate on the current google docs page. Anyway, regardless whether you make an extension or a standalone utility in python, I think the only proper method is to use API of these sites. Look for the documentation and examples. As for extensions start with an [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) or find a tutorial.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you!

Comment: @sinanspd Thanks for the heads up. I'll make sure to avoid posting such questions in the future. Cheers :)